# SQL Cant' get rid of duplicates when UNION two tables with some common records

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, union

I haven't been able to get around this: I Have two sets of data from 2 different tables,

```
SELECT V.CUST_CODE, V.NAME, V.REFER, M.AP_DTE, M.M_DTE,
(
  CAST((M.AMMT * M.SIGN)  + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00)) as FLOAT)
)  AS BLANCE

FROM CSTA_03.dbo.docBBlance V

LEFT JOIN CSTA_03.dbo.COLL_M03 M ON V.REFER = M.REFER AND V.CUST_CODE = M.CUST_CODE AND V.NUMB_CPT = M.NUMB_CPT
WHERE (((M.AMMT * M.SIGN) + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) > 1 OR ((M.AMMT * M.SIGN)+ (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) < -1) 
ORDER BY V.CUST_CODE
```

from which I get:

```
CUST_CODE   NAME    REFER   AP_DTE   M_DTE    BLANCE    
 1          A        1      03 -03   04-03    10.00 
 2          B        2      03 -03   04-03     5.00 
 1          A       10      03-20    04-20     7.00
```

The second query (from 2 diffrent tables):

```
SELECT  CDE_CUST, -- CDE_CUST same value as CUST_CODE (customer code)
    INV_CODE,
    STATUS,
    DOC_DTE,
    AMMT,
    DAT_FDSK
FROM CSTA_03.dbo.INVF03 INVF03

WHERE STATUS <> 'C' AND DOC_DTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

UNION

SELECT  CDE_CUST,
        INV_CODE,
        STATUS,
        DOC_DTE,
        (AMMT * -1),
        DAT_FDSK
FROM CSTA_03.dbo.INVD03 DV
WHERE STATUS <> 'C' AND DOC_DTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
```

Returns:

```
CUST_CODE   INV_NUM   STATUS    DOC_DTE   AMMT      DAT_FDSK
1           10        S         03-20      7.00     324
3           11                  03-20      3.50       0
```

What I need is two combine every row which has the same customer, invoice number and same date, and keep all the remaining rows, I have tried different approaches without success, the closest has been:

```
SELECT
    V.CUST_CODE AS CDE_CUST,
    V.NAME,
    V.REFER AS INV_CODE,
    '' AS STATUS,
    M.AP_DTE AS DOC_DTE, --same value as DOC_DTE (invoice date)
    M.M_DTE,
    0 AS AMMT,
    0 AS DAT_FDSK,
    ( CAST((M.AMMT * M.SIGN)  + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00)) as FLOAT))  AS BLANCE

FROM CSTA_03.dbo.docBBlance V

LEFT JOIN CSTA_03.dbo.COLL_M03 M ON V.REFER = M.REFER AND V.CUST_CODE = M.CUST_CODE AND V.NUMB_CPT = M.NUMB_CPT
WHERE (((M.AMMT * M.SIGN) + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) > 1 OR ((M.AMMT * M.SIGN)+ (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) < -1) 

UNION 

SELECT  B.CDE_CUST,
        B.NAME,
        B.INV_CODE,
        B.STATUS,
        B.DOC_DTE,
        B.M_DTE,
        B.AMMT,
        B.DAT_FDSK,
        B.BLANCE
FROM        
(
SELECT  CDE_CUST,
        NULL AS NAME,
        INV_CODE,
        STATUS,
        DOC_DTE,
        NULL as M_DTE,
        AMMT,
        DAT_FDSK,
        0 AS BLANCE

FROM CSTA_03.dbo.INVF03 INVF03
WHERE STATUS <> 'C' AND DOC_DTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

UNION

SELECT  CDE_CUST,


NULL AS NAME,
        INV_CODE,
        STATUS,
        DOC_DTE,
        NULL as M_DTE,
        (AMMT*-1) AS AMMT,
        DAT_FDSK,
        0 AS BLANCE
FROM CSTA_03.dbo.INVD03 DV
WHERE STATUS <> 'C' AND DOC_DTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
) AS B


ORDER BY V.CUST_CODE
```

that returns:

```
CUST_CODE   NAME    INV_CODE    STATUS  DOC_DTE M_DTE   AMMT    BLANCE  DAT_FDSK
1           A        1                   03-03  04-03           10.00   
1           A       10                   03-20  04-20            7.00   
1                   10          S        03-20           7.00            324
2           B        2                   03-03  04-03            5.00   
3                   11                   03-20           3.50              0
```

But that gives me duplicate rows (rows 2 and 3), which I just can´t get rid of, what I really need to get is where the info from same customer, doc and date is in same row (2nd row):

```
CUST_CODE   NAME    INV_CODE    STATUS  DOC_DTE M_DTE   AMMT    BLANCE  DAT_FDSK
1           A        1                  03-03   04-03           10.00   
1           A       10          S       03-20   04-20    7.00    7.00   324
2           B        2                  03-03   04-03            5.00   
3                   11                  03-20            3.50             0
```

Help will be super appreciated!!!

Comment: Instead of a union I would do a join by the CUST_CODE and INV_CODE.  I will post a query when I have the time, unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: Wrap your query with  `SELECT MAX(..), SUM(..) FROM (the query) q GROUP BY CUST_CODE,   INV_CODE,  DOC_DTE`

Comment: can't group by CUST_CODE there are customers who have plenty of docs

Answer (score 0):

You can take join on CDE_CUST,inv_code

```
select please_select_cols from ( SELECT V.CUST_CODE AS CDE_CUST, V.NAME, V.REFER AS INV_CODE, '' AS STATUS, M.AP_DTE AS DOC_DTE, --same value as DOC_DTE (invoice date) M.M_DTE, 0 AS AMMT, 0 AS DAT_FDSK, ( CAST((M.AMMT * M.SIGN) + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00)) as FLOAT)) AS BLANCE FROM CSTA_03.dbo.docBBlance V LEFT JOIN CSTA_03.dbo.COLL_M03 M 
ON V.REFER = M.REFER AND V.CUST_CODE = M.CUST_CODE AND 
V.NUMB_CPT = M.NUMB_CPT WHERE (((M.AMMT * M.SIGN) + (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) > 1 OR ((M.AMMT * M.SIGN)+ (ISNULL(V.BLANCE, 0.00))) < -1) ) as a join (SELECT B.CDE_CUST, B.NAME, B.INV_CODE, B.STATUS, B.DOC_DTE, B.M_DTE, B.AMMT, B.DAT_FDSK, B.BLANCE FROM ( SELECT CDE_CUST, NULL AS NAME, INV_CODE, STATUS, DOC_DTE, NULL as M_DTE, AMMT, DAT_FDSK, 0 AS BLANCE FROM
 CSTA_03.dbo.INVF03 INVF03 WHERE STATUS DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) ) as b 
on (a.CDE_CUST=b.CDE_CUST
 and a.inv_code=b.inv_code)
 join 
(SELECT CDE_CUST, NULL AS NAME, INV_CODE, STATUS, DOC_DTE, NULL as M_DTE, (AMMT*-1) AS AMMT, DAT_FDSK, 0 AS BLANCE FROM CSTA_03.dbo.INVD03 DV WHERE STATUS DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) ) AS B) as c on (a.CDE_CUST=c.CDE_CUST and a.inv_code=c.inv_code )
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn´t work because it leaves out all registers that doesn't on J.CVE_CLIE = K.CVE_CLPV and J.REFER = K.CVE_DOC

Comment: the second query, the one with UNION has to stay that way, tryed your approachm but still stuck, any other ideas?